# External storage media setting

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, storage, media-files

I have a samsung Galaxy S4 with an external 64Gb class 10 micro SD card. How can I set the settings to have all media (photos, movies, music) stored automatically in the external card when a pic is taken or files are downloaded?

Comment: There's no global switch for that. You'll have to do so in the apps you use, e.g. the camera app(s).

Comment: incredible, apps like wassapp don't even have a setting for this

Answer (score 1):

[ROOT ONLY]

A third party solution would be the App [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount). That way it is possible to move all the media folders one by one to the external SD Card and mount them on top of the internal folders.

Answer (score 0):

As I already shortly pointed out in my comment to the question itself: Android has no centralized setting for that, it has to be configured for each app separately – provided the app supports it. Unfortunately, such a setting is not even featured by all apps, so for some it might be impossible.